# Issue in transformation of SSIS dtsx file using File transformation in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, ssis-2012

I have dtsx file in which having two connection strings.

1. It is point to Azure storage account Fileshare.
2. It is point to Data Source connection.

e.g.

1. Connection string = Dev.file.core.windows.net\xxx\xxx\
2. Data Source = xx.xx.xx.xxx(IpAddress),User Id=XXX;Password=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;
   IPAdress like 15.10.52.192

Current connection strings having Development environment entry need to transform for Test,QA and Prod environment using Azure Devops.

I'm used File Transformation but it is not working in Azure DevOps pipeline.
Please suggest the solution for SSIS deployment for file transformation.

Comment: Do you get any error from the Azure Pipeline? Or did the transformation not work? What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add those connection strings as project variable in SSIS packages.
refer below blog on how to do it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15

Once you have these project parameters configured you should be able to change those in Azure dev ops build pipeline before deploying to Production, as those project level variables will be available to you in there.

Comment: Hi Amandeep, Thanks for rrply.

Comment: No worries. did it resolve the issue? if so please vote. 
If not please clarify the question further.

Comment: Hi Amandeep, Thanks for reply.                                                                                                          one more thing in dtsx file i see both connection start with                                                                 
  DTS:ConnectionString=  will it solve the issue?

Comment: after connection creation you can right click it and make it project level connection variable.